# How is each of the things different in cons of LISP?

Tags: lisp, cons

These are the outputs of different combinations of arguments to cons. I just started learning lisp. Can someone help me understand these ?

```
Break 80 [81]> (CONS '(A) 'B) 
((A) . B)
Break 80 [81]> (CONS '(A) '(B)) 
((A) B)
Break 80 [81]> (CONS 'A 'B) 
(A . B)
Break 80 [81]> (CONS 'A '(B)) 
(A B)
Break 80 [81]>
```

Comment: [Here.](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html)

Comment: [**14.1 Cons Concepts**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/14_a.htm)

Comment: +1 for experimenting on your own and methodically trying permutations of inputs combinations (this is good!), but -1 for lack of research effort (you haven't shown any attempt to find any documentation about conses, lists, etc.).

Comment: Also see [Dot notation in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20216711/1281433).  Scheme and Common Lisp are not exactly the same, but that question is applicable to lots (all?) of different languages in the Lisp family.  The key you need right now may be that all conses are the same, but certain "combinations" of conses get *printed* in a special way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lisp difference between (cons 'a (cons 'b 'c)) and (cons 'a '(b.c))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859505/lisp-difference-between-cons-a-cons-b-c-and-cons-a-b-c)

Answer (score 1):

The **cons** function always does the same thing: it produces a *cons cell* of its arguments.  A cons cell is simply a pair.  You can get the first element of the pair with **car** and the second element with **cdr**.

For *writing* a literal cell, you can quote and use the notation **(x . y)** where **x** is the **car** and **y** is the **cdr**.  Using this notation, you can write your examples as follows (but don't just take my word for it, try it in the REPL):

```
> '((A) .  B ) ;=> ((A) . B)
> '((A) . (B)) ;=> ((A) B)
> '( A  .  B ) ;=> (A . B)
> '( A  . (B)) ;=> (A B)
```

But why don't the results of the second and fourth cases *print* the same way that we wrote them?  There are special printing conventions for cons cells, because we use cons cells to implement linked lists.

Read [14.1.2 Conses as Lists](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/14_ab.htm) for specifics, but a list is a cons cell whose car is the first element of the list, and whose cdr is the rest of the list (i.e., another list).  That means that the list **(1 2 3)** is the same as (using the literal dotted pair notation) **(1 . (2 . (3 . nil)))**.  You can try that in the REPL:

```
> '(1 . (2 . (3 . nil))) ;=> (1 2 3)
```

That's a very useful printing (and input) convention for a language where lists are so fundamental.  I've written more about this in an answer to other questions, too:

- [Dot notation in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20216711/1281433)
- [Recursive range in Lisp adds a period?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16379657/1281433)

Comment: @WillNess sorry! comment deleted.

Comment: why sorry? don't mention it == you're welcome, is it not? :) This comment will self-destruct after yours is. :)

Comment: @WillNess 'twas just a joke. You said "don't mention it" so I deleted my comment. :)